# two different styles per one HTML5 placeholder attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently want to simply style my asterisk within my `placeholder=""` copy to be red and leave the the rest of the placeholder copy my shade of blue I'm using in the below.

**HTML MARK-UP:**

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="* First Name" required>
```

**CSS in which I am styling placeholder copy to be blue:**

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    #6785b2;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #6785b2;
   opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #6785b2;
   opacity:  1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    #6785b2;
}
```

**Any thoughts as to how to achieve this?**

I would ideally not use background image, as I am already using a background image for a simple custom down arrow on select boxes, also my fields have different sizes so I really don't want to use multiple background images, but instead seeking a more global solution... Specific to still using and styling `placeholder` attribute.

[image]

Comment: It appears you're wanting to use the placeholder instead of properly labeling your input field. This practice is strongly discouraged by the HTML5 specification. See the reasoning here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking for something like this (demo is WebKit only): http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/wKqLOM

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #6785b2;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder::before {
  content: '*';
  color: #FF8F20;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}
```

Comment: As he states it's only for webkit browsers. Meaning Chrome and Safari primarily. Do you not care about those using Firefox or IE? Does it work on mobile browsers? They are not going to see that those fields are required. Just saying dude. You should really consider following HTML5 specifications and recommendations whenever possible.

Comment: My demo is WebKit only (because I'm lazy), but you can extend usage of `::before` pseudo-element to each and every browser that supports styling of placeholders.

Comment: That is true and I stand corrected. My actual point is that the use of placeholders without proper labeling on input fields is strongly discouraged by HTML5 specs. I may be assuming too much here but that appears to be the plan. And since the placeholder attribute is new to HTML5 older browsers won't show anything except the input box. IE9 and earlier will show empty input fields with no labels and no placeholder.